# Mobile browsers add a gap at the end of final element via css gap property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm back on Stack Overflow after a long time because I'm truly stuck at an issue I cannot get around even after hours piling up in front of the screen.

I have made a simple widget using CSS + HTML + JavaScript which scrolls elements in an overflowing-x container. [image: Chromium 91.0.4472.77 Desktop]

It works in a simple way, there is JavaScript code that adds a `205` value to the property `scrollLeft` of the overflowing container. The number comes from the fixed width of the images + the gap value which is 5px. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="controlContainer">
    <a class="adButton" onclick="Scroll(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <div id="topics">
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(1)">
            <p>History</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/hundredgates.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(2)">
            <p>Oceans</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/goldensea.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(3)">
            <p>Sports</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/kite_surf.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem"  onclick="ChangeTopic(4)">
            <p>Travel</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/antiparos_church.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(5)">
            <p>Nightlife</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/nightlife.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="adButton" onclick="Scroll(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#controlContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    gap: 20px;
}

#topics {
    
    display: inherit;
    
    gap: 5px;
    
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.adItem {
    position: relative;
}

.adItem img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.adItem p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffff;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    user-select: none;
    pointer: default:
    
}
```

And finally JS, which still needs some work tbh:

```
var LastClick;
var Delay = 300;
var SelectedElement;
var adControl;
var currentScroll;

window.onload = function () {SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad1"); adControl = document.getElementById("topics"); resizeController();};
window.onresize = debounce(() => resizeController());; //resize the container when the screen does

//window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad1")});

function Scroll(n) {
    if (LastClick >= (Date.now() - Delay)) {
        return;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        adControl.scrollLeft += 205;
        checkPos();
    } else if (n == -1) {
        adControl.scrollLeft -= 205;
        checkPos();
    }
    LastClick = Date.now();
    console.log(adControl.scrollLeft);
}; // This function is what's handling scrolling. THey are called via onclick events on the HTML Button elements

function checkPos() {
    var elementWidth = adControl.scrollLeft;
    if (elementWidth % 5 === 0) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        var newWidth = Math.ceil(elementWidth/5)*5;
        console.log("old width: %s, new width: %s", elementWidth, newWidth)
        adControl.scrollLeft = newWidth;
    } 
}; //Some position checks... it basically calculates if scrollLeft is divisible by 5, because all images are 200px long plus the 5px gap, so that should always be a multiple of 5.

function ChangeTopic(id) {
    SelectedElement.style.display = "none";
    SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad" + id);
    SelectedElement.style.display = "flex";
}; //That just changes the topic of another element.

function debounce(func, timeout = 1000){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}; //This is a debounce function for the resize event, it prevents it from firing it too much.

function resizeController() {
    adControl.style.maxWidth = "";
    var elementWidth = adControl.offsetWidth;
    var scroll = adControl.ScrollLeft;
    var itemNo = (Math.floor(elementWidth / 200))
    if (itemNo > 3) {
        itemNo = 3  
    };
    var newWidth = (itemNo*200);
    newWidth = newWidth+(5*itemNo) 
    
    adControl.style.maxWidth = (newWidth + "px");
    if (currentNo = itemNo) {
        adControl.scrollLeft = scroll;
    } 
}; //resizes the container if need be (for mobile or tablet devices)
```

It actually works very well on Desktop, but on mobile, the CSS `gap` property which adds the gap between the images also adds a gap at the last element, like this:

[image: Firefox 89.1.1 Mobile]

That's even when I use a different browser from Firefox, like Chrome

On desktop, this gap does not exist, regardless of browser once again:

[image: Chromium 91.0.4472.77 Desktop]

What is this? And how can I solve it? The main problem this causes is it will scroll in that tiny 5 gap space, which throws the position of my elements out of place, making them look like this:

[image: Firefox]

I've thought of different methods like checking the property of ScrollLeft to detect when the view is out of the elements, but that property is completely unpredictable. For instance, when I scroll to the beginning of the element, it's not going to be necessarily zero, and even if I reach the end, the 205 value will be added even if there is not any space on the container. So that isn't reliable.

In short, I'd either need some kind of method to keep that gapping behaviour in check or solve the root problem altogether.

Yes... I'm not using any framework at all, my entire project is built on pure JavaScript. I'm not sure why I did this to myself, but oh well, all the challenge I guess.

Comment: please add a fiddle so others can check this on their own, otherwise you are unlikely to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and resize your font on the paragraph elements in your
div class="adItem" it appears to be overlapping the container and causing what would appear to be extra padding and i don't think it's happening on the others because the text is not long enough on others.

```js
var LastClick;
var Delay = 300;
var SelectedElement;
var adControl;
var currentScroll;

window.onload = function () {SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad1"); adControl = document.getElementById("topics"); resizeController();};
window.onresize = debounce(() => resizeController());; //resize the container when the screen does

//window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad1")});

function Scroll(n) {
    if (LastClick >= (Date.now() - Delay)) {
        return;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        adControl.scrollLeft += 205;
        checkPos();
    } else if (n == -1) {
        adControl.scrollLeft -= 205;
        checkPos();
    }
    LastClick = Date.now();
    console.log(adControl.scrollLeft);
}; // This function is what's handling scrolling. THey are called via onclick events on the HTML Button elements

function checkPos() {
    var elementWidth = adControl.scrollLeft;
    if (elementWidth % 5 === 0) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        var newWidth = Math.ceil(elementWidth/5)*5;
        console.log("old width: %s, new width: %s", elementWidth, newWidth)
        adControl.scrollLeft = newWidth;
    } 
}; //Some position checks... it basically calculates if scrollLeft is divisible by 5, because all images are 200px long plus the 5px gap, so that should always be a multiple of 5.

function ChangeTopic(id) {
    SelectedElement.style.display = "none";
    SelectedElement = document.getElementById("ad" + id);
    SelectedElement.style.display = "flex";
}; //That just changes the topic of another element.

function debounce(func, timeout = 1000){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}; //This is a debounce function for the resize event, it prevents it from firing it too much.

function resizeController() {
    adControl.style.maxWidth = "";
    var elementWidth = adControl.offsetWidth;
    var scroll = adControl.ScrollLeft;
    var itemNo = (Math.floor(elementWidth / 200))
    if (itemNo > 3) {
        itemNo = 3  
    };
    var newWidth = (itemNo*200);
    newWidth = newWidth+(5*itemNo) 
    
    adControl.style.maxWidth = (newWidth + "px");
    if (currentNo = itemNo) {
        adControl.scrollLeft = scroll;
    } 
}; //resizes the container if need be (for mobile or tablet devices)
```

```css
#controlContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    gap: 20px;
}

#topics {
    
    display: inherit;
    
    gap: 5px;
    
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.adItem {
    position: relative;
}

.adItem img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.adItem p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    top: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffff;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    user-select: none;
    pointer: default:
    
}
```

```html
<div id="controlContainer">
    <a class="adButton" onclick="Scroll(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <div id="topics">
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(1)">
            <p>History</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/hundredgates.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(2)">
            <p>Oceans</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/goldensea.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(3)">
            <p>Sports</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/kite_surf.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem"  onclick="ChangeTopic(4)">
            <p>Travel</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/antiparos_church.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="adItem" onclick="ChangeTopic(5)">
            <p>Nightlife</p>
            <img src="images/other_samples/nightlife.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="adButton" onclick="Scroll(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Christ almighty, I can't believe I spent so many hours writing all kinds of code and it ends up being the text. How embarrassing! I thought I'd leave making the text responsive last because the inspector wasn't reporting the img element to be more than 200px, but it was overflowing, and I ended up paying this price. Unbelievable. I thought it was weird how Chrome and Firefox had the exact same behaviour even though their engines were completely different. Thanks a lot!